# How to create a new variable in a data frame in R to identify first non NA occurence in raws considering col names

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a problem with a data frame in R. I want to compute a new variable to show the first non occurence of `NA` in rows of my data frame. The `dput()` versión of my data is next:

```
structure(list(ID = c("1387894", "533575", "219918", "734589", 
"1182091", "1442171", "880182", "2510982", "1533943", "2306853", 
"1300782"), s1 = c("A", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), s2 = c("A", NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA), 
    s3 = c("A", NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, "A", "A", "A", NA, NA), 
    s4 = c("A", NA, "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", NA, NA
    ), s5 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A")), .Names = c("ID", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data shows of this form:

```
ID      s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
1387894 A   A   A   A   A
533575  A   NA  NA  NA  A
219918  NA  A   A   A   A
734589  NA  A   A   A   A
1182091 NA  NA  A   A   A
1442171 NA  NA  NA  A   A
880182  NA  A   A   A   A
2510982 NA  A   A   A   A
1533943 NA  A   A   A   A
2306853 NA  NA  NA  NA  A
1300782 NA  NA  NA  NA  A
```

I want to compute a `V` variable that shows the first non ocurrence of `NA` in each row considering that `s1` shows first position, `s2` second position,..., `s5` fiveth position. I want to get something like this:

```
    ID      s1  s2  s3  s4  s5 V
    1387894 A   A   A   A   A  1
    533575  A   NA  NA  NA  A  1
    219918  NA  A   A   A   A  2
    734589  NA  A   A   A   A  2
    1182091 NA  NA  A   A   A  3
    1442171 NA  NA  NA  A   A  4
    880182  NA  A   A   A   A  2
    2510982 NA  A   A   A   A  2
    1533943 NA  A   A   A   A  2
    2306853 NA  NA  NA  NA  A  5
    1300782 NA  NA  NA  NA  A  5
```

How you can see, for example in the last row, the first non occurence of `NA` is in `s5` and `V` has a value of 5 due to that. I don't have a clear idea of how to make this maybe considering a index for col names. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to `apply` across the rows and use `which.max` on your logical comparison...

```
apply( df[,-1] , 1 , function(x) which.max( ! is.na(x) ) )
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
# 1  1  2  2  3  4  2  2  2  5  5
```

Comment: +1! Just to add something similar: `apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) Position(Negate(is.na), x))` that -I guess- will be slower, but "classier"! :)